# How to automatically determine if there is NO seasonality from PSD/FFT of time series in python?

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

I have around 1000 different time series, and for each one of them I want to automatically determine if there is any seasonality in the time series.

Given the assumption that there is seasonality present, it is easy to determine periodicity from FFT or PSD.

But how do you automatically decide that there is **no** seasonality or periodicity in the signal based on FFT or PSD?

```
def psd_time_series(y):
   yAC = np.correlate(Y-np.mean(Y), Y-np.mean(Y), mode='full')
   yAC = yAC/np.max(yAC) # not necessary, but scales large values
   fft_yAC= np.fft.fft(yAC)
   freqs = np.arange(0,len(fft_yAC))/len(fft_yAC)
   psd = 10*np.log10(np.abs(fft_yAC)/max(np.abs(fft_yAC))
   return psd,freqs

def determine_if_seasonal(psd):
    ### part I need help with

def detect_seasonality(y):

   psd,freqs = psd_time_series(y)
  
   seasonality = ... #### do some check of PSD to determine if seasonal

   if seasonality:
       periodicity = round(1/freqs[psd.argsort()[::-1]][0])
   else:
       periodicity = None
   return periodicity
```

**What would be a way of automatically determining that a single spike or Gaussian noise does not have seasonality based on the FFT or PSD of the time series? Is there any rule of thumb for the threshold of the magnitude of PSD? The prominence of peaks? Height of peaks?**

For example, a PSD plot of a single spike might look like

[image]

FFT of a single spike

[image]

Or PSD of Gaussian noise might look like

[image: ![enter image description here]

FFT of Gaussian noise

[image]

Or PSD of an actual signal with periodicity might look like

[image]

FFT of the same signal

[image]

Appreciate any input or insights.

Comment: I would vote to close this question, but I can't since it has a bounty. It does not, to me, seem like a programming question, but rather one about signal processing. Imagine you were to solve the underlying conceptual signal processing question – "how can I use FFTs to discover (a)periodicity in this type of signal?" – would there really be any question left? The part about Python seems tangential. Maybe the [signal processing stack exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) is a good fit?

Comment: @gspr Maybe you are right, I suppose I can't remove the bounty and close it? Haven't used bounty before.

Comment: No idea, sorry.

Comment: I think bounties are [non-refundable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). If I have time I may try to give you an answer during the week. What I can tell now is that the PSD peaks are pronounced only when you have several periods. Is it possible for you to sample the data for many periods?

Answer (score 2):

This answer comes with a disclaimer that I haven't had to do this type of time series analysis in over 15 years and am therefore **very** rusty. I would very much welcome any corrections since I am working from memory and may well have forgotten a few things. Hopefully, though it gives you some ideas of how I think you'd want to do something like this if your data allows, and you can refine the approach. (If you do please reply or edit the answer!)

As I mentioned in a comment above, if you can break your dataset into multiple segments, you can start to gain some confidence limits on the energy at different frequencies in your dataset. Of course, this means you need long datasets which may or may not be available depending on what you're doing. But like any statistical technique, if you don't have a lot of data it's hard to be confident in what you find. I am going to go about describing how I would decide that there was a signal, and you can invert it to find where there is *not* a signal.

The first thing I would do is break up the dataset into sections. How many you can break it into would depend on how long your data set is relative to the periodicity of the signal you are trying to find (or not find, in your case). One thing that you can do to get more segments is to overlap them, but to conserve energy you need to filter with an appropriate window. In my code below I assume a 50% overlap and apply a [Hanning window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hann_function). I honestly forget the details of different windows and overlaps, so I apologize I can't give more information on why I chose this overlap with this window.

Hopefully, from your dataset you can come up with a distribution or expectation of what your background state is. Perhaps it's just a white noise floor or something more complex that is red-shifted or blue-shifted. The level of the background of the power spectrum should give you information on the noise level since the power spectral energy relates to the noise as `2 * noise**2 / (fs * L)`, where `fs` is the sampling frequency and `L` is the window length. This is all if I remember right, like I said I'm very rusty.

First, let's take a look at the power spectra of noise and noise with a signal superimposed.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def detrend(y):
    # This function removes the linear trend from the time series
    # by fitting y = mx + b to x and then subtracting it
    x = np.arange(len(y))
    A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T
    m, b = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y, rcond=None)[0]
    return(y - m * x - b)

def subset(f, L, overlap, fs):
    # Break the function f into sections of length L.
    # Normally you do some overlapping of sections,
    # and you want to use an appropriate window
    # to conserve the energy in the time series signal.
    # Here I use a Hanning window.
    N = len(f)
    x = []
    for i in range(0, int(N-L+1), int(L * overlap)):
        window = np.hanning(L)
        y = detrend(f[i:i+L]) * window
        fft = np.fft.fft(y)
        fft = fft[:len(fft)//2+1]
        x.append(np.real(fft * np.conj(fft)) / (fs * L))
    return(x)

def noise(N):
    # Create a white noise field
    return(np.random.random(N) - 0.5)

N = 10**4 # length of time series
dt = 1    # sampling period
fs = 2 * np.pi / dt # sampling frequency
nyquist = fs / 2 # nyquist frequency
t = np.linspace(dt, N * dt, N) # times of data collection


L = N // 100 # window size used for subsampling
overlap = 0.5 # overlap in windows

# frequencies that will come out of the fft
# you can also use fp.fft.fftfreq and adjust
freqs = np.linspace(0, nyquist, L//2+1) 

# Create background white noise
noise_amplitude = 3
energy_scale = 2 * noise_amplitude**2 / (fs * L)
WhiteNoise = np.array(subset(noise_amplitude * noise(N), L, overlap, fs) ) / energy_scale

# Create another timeseries with a signal and noise
omega = 2 * np.pi / 10 # frequency in dataset
signal = (noise_amplitude / 4) * np.cos(t * omega)  # signal in dataset
data = signal + noise_amplitude * noise(N) # dataset
DataSet    = np.array(subset(data,  L, overlap, fs)) / energy_scale

# Percentiles of White Noise Power Spectra, for plotting
Wprct = np.percentile(WhiteNoise, [2.5, 25, 50, 75, 97.5], axis = 0)

# Percentiles of Data Power Spectra, for plotting
Dprct = np.percentile(DataSet, [2.5, 25, 50, 75, 97.5], axis = 0)

fig = plt.figure()
# Plot the spectra from all the subsets of the noise
for w in WhiteNoise:
    plt.semilogy(freqs[1:], w[1:], 'k', alpha = 0.05)

# Plot the median and confidence intervales
lines, = plt.semilogy(freqs[1:], Wprct[2,1:], label = 'Median of noise floor')
plt.fill_between(freqs[1:], Wprct[1,1:], Wprct[3,1:], alpha = 0.8, color = lines.get_color(), label = '50% CI of noise floor')
plt.fill_between(freqs[1:], Wprct[0,1:], Wprct[1,1:], alpha = 0.4, color = lines.get_color(), label = '95% CI of noise floor')
plt.fill_between(freqs[1:], Wprct[3,1:], Wprct[4,1:], alpha = 0.4, color = lines.get_color())

lines, = plt.plot(freqs[1:], Dprct[2,1:], label = 'Median signal-to-noise estimate')

plt.plot([omega, omega], [10**-3, 100], 'k:', label = 'Signal in dataset')
plt.plot([freqs[1], freqs[-1]], [1, 1], 'r:', label = 'Noise floor')
plt.legend()
 
plt.xlabel('Angular frequency')
plt.ylabel('Energy above noise floor [db]')
```

[image: psd of signals]

It's pretty clear that the signal is poking through the noise, but I think we can up with something better than "eye-balling it". In the code below, I just look at the number of points at each frequency of my "dataset" that are above the noise distribution and scale accordingly. Pulling values from noise gives a 50% chance that your value will be greater than the noise, so
you want your signal considerably above 50%. (On the flip side, if the value is less that 50%, that's telling you the signal is *below* the noise floor, which would be interesting.) There are [more advanced approaches](http://www.talkstats.com/threads/probability-of-one-random-variable-being-greater-than-another.3987/), which I didn't get into here, but I think would give the same result.

```
plt.figure()
for i in range(1, len(freqs)):
    x = 0
    for j in range(len(DataSet[:,i])):
        x += np.sum(DataSet[j,i] > WhiteNoise[:,i])
    x /= len(DataSet[:,i])**2
    plt.plot(freqs[i], x, 'k.')
plt.plot([omega, omega], [0.4, 1], 'k:', label = 'Signal in dataset')
plt.xlabel('Angular frequency')
plt.ylabel('Probability signal is greater than noise')
plt.legend()
```

[image: probability signal > noise]

I think someone could use these methods to say where there is and is not a oscillation at different frequencies, which should get to your question about seasonality of a dataset.

Comment: Agree with @gspr that this is more of a signals problem than a coding one, but also reading above that your bounty may be non-refundable I wanted to give you something. Please double-check on the signal processing stack exchange to make sure I'm not leading you astray.

Comment: Another thought looking at the second figure. If you look at the distribution where you have noise (hovering around 0.5)---which I assume would be normal---you can start to estimate the likelihood that the values near the signal frequency are noise.

Answer (score 0):

This is a signal processing question, but you probably want to calculate the power spectrum density, which can be done easily using [scipy.signal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html) and then set a reasonable threshold for total power to assign periodicity.

There's a much longer answer to a similar question (not mine) [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16169)

Comment: Yes, to add to eschibli's information and the related post, the PSD should show how much energy is at each frequency in your dataset. Ideally, your datasets would be long enough that you can cut them into sections with some overlap using something like a Hanning window. That way you can ensemble your time series and get error bars on your spectral energy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use autocorrelation function or partial auto correlation function. You will get a coefficient for every size of lags (periods) which will measure the similarity of a signal with a delayed version of it. Make sure you use lags bigger than some periods (>5), and if all coefficients are smaller than a threshold (lets say, 0.5, but i don't find any theoretical approach to support this decision), than your signal has no seasonality.

Comment: i can add code to automatic make this if you want, and if moderators agree on not delete/close the question.